# Count vectors in list with the same elements in r

Tags: r, list

I have a list of ~8000 vectors, and I would like to know how many duplicates there are of these 8000 vectors, but the order of the elements in each could be different.

for example:

```
list <- c()
list[[1]] <- c(1,2,3) 
list[[2]] <- c(2,1,3)
list[[3]] <- c(3,2,1)
list[[4]] <- c(4,5)
list[[5]] <- c(5,4)
list[[6]] <- c(1,2,3,5)
```

should give me a count of 3 for `c(1,2,3)` and 2 for `c(4,5)` and 1 for `c(1,2,3,5)`

I'd like the count of each of the duplicates, not just how many are duplicated.

Comment: Do you need `length(unique(list))`  Also, if you need all the duplicates then `sum(duplicated(lst)|duplicated(lst, fromLast = TRUE))`

Comment: in a sense, but I would like some sort of function that tells me which list was duplicated how many times, in the example above it would be `c(1,2,3) = 3` or something like that

Comment: What you are showing is not a list of lists but a list of vectors

Comment: You have a typo: `List` should be `list` on your first line

Comment: yes, thanks. Was trying to make it reproducible but that part slipped through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtools)

get_perm <- function(v) {
  m <- permutations(n = length(v), r = length(v), v = v, set = F)
  m[order(c(m))]
}

all <- map(list, get_perm)

unique <- map(list, get_perm) %>% unique()

res_vec <- c()
element <- c()

for(i in seq_along(unique)) {
  element[[i]] <- unique[[i]] %>% unique() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  res_vec[[i]] <- all %in% unique[i] %>% sum()
}

tibble(
  elements = unlist(element),
  numbers = res_vec
)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  elements       numbers
  <chr>          <int>
1 1,2,3              3
2 4,5                2
3 1,2,3,5            1
```

`elements` contains all the individual elements of the vectors for each group and `numbers` are the numbers of vectors you have in each group.

Answer (score 1):

We create a function to take `vector` as an argument ('val'), then loop through the `list` with `sapply`, check if `all` the 'val`are`%in%`the 'x', and`sum`the logical`vector`

```
f1 <- function(lst, val) sum(sapply(lst, function(x) all(val %in% x)))
f1(list, c(1, 2, 3))
[#1] 3

f1(list, c(4, 5))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: So actually this half worked..
I'm not getting extra counts when the vectors contain more elements, example `c<-(1,2,3,5)` is being counted with `c(1,2,3)` how would I fix that?

Comment: I've resorted to sorting the vectors and then using == instead of %in%. that's the only way I can think of for now. Would appreciate any other solutions.